# Independence of log-returns under Heston model

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston

I first precise that I am new to QuantSE.

Heston is a widely used moodel but I have some doubts on it and I couldn't find a proper answer on the internet.

1. How can we prove that Heston in not and exponential Lévy model ?
2. Are the log-returns of Heston model independent ?

Any hint, advice or reference will be highly  appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: 2 is easy, Heston log returns are not independent. Not sure what you are asking for 1?

Comment: Thank you @river_rat ! For 1. Heston is an affine model, but how one could show that it is not an exponential Levy ? For 2. How do you get that ? Thanks !